# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(XO)[AEe -> mu -> mu]: Error while Upgrading angular version 9 to version 17?

Tags: angular9, angular17, versionupgrade

I am trying to upgrade angular v9 to v17. So move with the approach by upgrading all packages that support version 17. After that, I fixed all the errors that came in the terminal. so at last I got only warnings and at the console, I got JIT Compiler unavailable. which i fixed by making aot = false after that i got this

```
 main.js:34 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(XO)[AEe -> mu -> mu]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for mu!
    at ole.get (main.js:34:24830)
    at xK.get (main.js:34:26419)
    at xK.get (main.js:34:2641`<kbd>your text</kbd>`9)
    at z4t (main.js:4:2123)
    at pl (main.js:4:2204)
    at Object.AEe_Factory [as factory] (ɵfac.js:1:1)
    at xK.hydrate (main.js:34:27192)
    at xK.get (main.js:34:26332)
    at fSe.get (main.js:34:56013)
    at b8e (main.js:7:15406)
```

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MatMomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { FuseModule } from '@fuse/fuse.module';
import { FuseSharedModule } from '@fuse/shared.module';
import { FuseProgressBarModule, FuseSidebarModule, FuseThemeOptionsModule } from '@fuse/components';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { fuseConfig } from 'app/fuse-config';
import { DatePipe, PlatformLocation, APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import 'hammerjs';
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';

import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS, DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';

import { LoaderComponent } from './common/loader/loader.component';
import { LoaderInterceptor } from './common/loader/loader.interceptor';
import { LoaderService } from './common/loader/loader.service';
import { BaseService } from './services/base.service';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from './common/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import { ShowDialogComponent } from './common/show-dialog/show-dialog.component';
import { DialogService } from './common/confirm-dialog/dialog.service';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './helpers/error.interceptor';
import { BasicAuthInterceptor } from './helpers/basic-auth.interceptor';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/login/login.component';
import { ProgressBarModelComponent } from './common/progress-bar-model/progress-bar-model.component';
import { HttpService } from './services/http.service';
import { IgmiteModule } from './main/igmite.module';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { FakeDbService } from './fake-db/fake-db.service';
import { ProjectDashboardModule } from './dashboards/dashboard.module';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { MatTableExporterModule } from 'mat-table-exporter';
// import { fuseperfectscrollbaroptions }

export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: "DD/MM/YYYY"
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: "DD/MM/YYYY",
        monthYearLabel: "MM YYYY",
        dateA11yLabel: "DD/MM/YYYY",
        monthYearA11yLabel: "MM YYYY"
    }
};

export function getBaseHref(platformLocation: PlatformLocation): string {
    return platformLocation.getBaseHrefFromDOM();
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }, // otherwise redirect to summary-dashboard
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoaderComponent,
        ConfirmDialogComponent,
        ShowDialogComponent,
        ProgressBarModelComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        QuillModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        NgIdleKeepaliveModule.forRoot(),

        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(FakeDbService, {
            delay: 0,
            passThruUnknownUrl: true
        }),
        
        // Material moment date module
        MatMomentDateModule,
        // FormsModule,    //added here too
        // MatPaginator,
        // ReactiveFormsModule, //added here too
        // Material
        MatTableExporterModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatDialogModule,

        // Fuse modules
        FuseModule.forRoot(fuseConfig),
        FuseProgressBarModule,
        FuseSharedModule,
        FuseSidebarModule,
        FuseThemeOptionsModule,
        // App modules
        LayoutModule,
        ProjectDashboardModule,
        IgmiteModule
    ],
    exports: [
        // MatPaginator
        LoaderComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        
        DatePipe,
        BaseService,`your text`
        DialogService,
        HttpService,
        CookieService, 
        LoaderService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: LoaderInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: "en_IN" }, //you can change useValue
        {
            provide: DateAdapter,
            useClass: MomentDateAdapter
        },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
        {
            provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
            useFactory: getBaseHref,
            deps: [PlatformLocation]
        },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
    static injector: Injector;

    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        console.log({
            injector
        })
        AppModule.injector = injector;
    }
}
```

Here is Package.json file

```
{
    "name": "fuse",
    "version": "9.0.0",
    "license": "https://themeforest.net/licenses/terms/regular",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --open",
        "start-hmr": "ng serve --configuration hmr --source-map=false --hmr-warning=false",
        "start-hmr-sourcemaps": "ng serve --configuration hmr --source-map=true --hmr-warning=false",
        "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev",
        "build-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev --stats-json",`your text`
        "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
        "build-prod-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/common": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/core": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
        "@angular/forms": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/localize": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/material": "^17.1.1",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/router": "17.1.1",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
        "@ng-idle/core": "14.0.0",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "14.0.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "17.0.1",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "17.0.1",
        "@ngrx/store": "17.0.1",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "17.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "12.0.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
        "@swimlane/dragula": "3.8.0",
        "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "20.4.1",
        "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.1.0",
        "@types/crypto-js": "4.1.1",
        "@types/prismjs": "1.26.3",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.17.0",
        "bootstrap": "5.3.0",
        "crypto-js": "4.1.1",
        "date-fns": "3.2.0",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "guid-typescript": "1.0.9",
        "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
        "html2canvas": "1.4.1",
        "lodash": "4.17.15",
        "mat-select-filter": "^2.4.1",
        "mat-table-exporter": "^15.0.0",
        "moment": "2.30.0",
        "ngx-color-picker": "16.0.0",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "17.0.1",
        "ngx-device-detector": "7.0.0",
        "ngx-mat-file": "^1.0.4",
        "ngx-mat-file-input": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
        "ngx-material-file-input": "^4.0.1",
        "ngx-quill": "24.0.4",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.5",
        "prismjs": "1.29.0",
        "quill": "^1.3.7",
        "rxjs": "7.8.1",
        "tslib": "2.6.2",
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
        "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
        "zone.js": "0.14.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/cli": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/language-service": "17.1.2",
        "@angularclass/hmr": "3.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "5.1.4",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.202",
        "@types/node": "20.10.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.20.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.20.0",
        "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
        "eslint": "8.56.0",
        "jasmine-core": "5.1.1",
        "karma": "6.4.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.2.0",
        "karma-coverage": "2.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.1.0",
        "ts-node": "10.9.2",
        "tslint": "5.18.0",
        "typescript": "5.2.2",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.10.1"
    }
}
```

here is angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "fuse": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "inlineStyle": true,
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild",
          "options": {
            "aot": false,
            "outputPath": "dist/fuse",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "optimization": {
              "fonts": {
                "inline": true
              },
              "scripts": true,
              "styles": {
                "inlineCritical": false,
                "minify": true
              }
            },
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js"

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                  "maximumError": "20mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "100kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "aws": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.aws.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "lahi": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.lahi.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "gj": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.gj.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "mh": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.mh.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "jh": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.jh.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "od": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.od.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ec": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": true
            },

            "hmr": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.hmr.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "fuse:build",
            "port": 4213
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "fuse:build:production"
            },
            "aws": {
              "buildTarget": "fuse:build:aws"
            },
            "lahi": {
              "buildTarget": "fuse:build:lahi"
            },
            "gj": {
              "buildTarget": "fuse:build:gj"
            },
            "mh": {
              "buildTarget": "fuse:build:mh"
            },
            "jh": {
              "buildTarget": "fuse:build:jh"
            },
            "od": {
              "buildTarget": "fuse:build:od"
            },
            "hmr": {
              "hmr": true,
              "buildTarget": "fuse:build:hmr"
            },
            "ec": {
              "buildTarget": "fuse:build:ec"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "fuse:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",`your text`
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "fuse:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "fuse:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "272c2101-67e2-4887-8849-6a69f012ab38",
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
}
```

and here is main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { hmrBootstrap } from 'hmr';

if ( environment.production )
{
    enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

if ( environment.hmr )
{
    if ( module['hot'] )
    {
        hmrBootstrap(module, bootstrap);
    }
    else
    {
        console.error('HMR is not enabled for webpack-dev-server!');
        console.log('Are you using the --hmr flag for ng serve?');
    }
}
else
{
    bootstrap().catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

and here is tsconfig.json file

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { hmrBootstrap } from 'hmr';

if ( environment.production )
{
    enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

if ( environment.hmr )
{
    if ( module['hot'] )
    {
        hmrBootstrap(module, bootstrap);
    }
    else
    {
        console.error('HMR is not enabled for webpack-dev-server!');
        console.log('Are you using the --hmr flag for ng serve?');
    }
}
else
{
    bootstrap().catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

able to know about the depreciated packages and NullInjector error should get resolved.